# How to pass/send data received from an api call in a particular screen(Login screen) to a seperate screen(Home Screen)using provider?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, flutter-provider

The control flow is as follows

I have one function that makes an api call that returns a string accesscode(logUserin()).

Then the second function (getUserdetailsFromApi()) gets called that takes in input which is the response of the first function call. The second function call returns a map that contains user details.

The second function gets called inside the first function and the first function gets called when the user clicks login button.

My issue is that i cant create a seperate class that extends changenotifier to run the second function because that class cannot receive the data that gets returned from the first function call(loggedinUseraccessCode). Therefore i an unable to use provider to send the data received from the second function call to the Homescreen of my app.

Heres my stateful login class

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Loginpage';
  var loggedInUserAccessCode;

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextStyle defaultStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15.0);
  TextStyle linkStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue);
  bool showSpinner = false;

  String email = '';

  String password = '';

  String? loginErrormessage;

  var loggedinUserRefreshCode;

  var userFirstname;

  var userLastname;

  var userEmail;


  void startSpinning() {
    setState(() {
      showSpinner = true;
    });
  }

  void stopSpinning() {
    setState(() {
      showSpinner = false;
    });
  }

  void getUserDetailsFromApi() async {
    var headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${widget.loggedInUserAccessCode}'};
    var request = http.Request(
        'GET', Uri.parse('link hidden'));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      final decodedResult = jsonDecode(responseString);
      userFirstname = decodedResult['first_name'];
      userLastname = decodedResult['last_name'];
      userEmail = decodedResult['email'];
    
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  void logUserIn() async {
    try {
      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
          'POST', Uri.parse('link hidden for privacy'));
      request.fields.addAll({
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
      });
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        final decodedResult = jsonDecode(responseString);
        widget.loggedInUserAccessCode = decodedResult['access'];
        loggedinUserRefreshCode = decodedResult['refresh'];
        stopSpinning();
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, MainScreen.id);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SuccessLoginSnackbar);
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        final decodedResult = jsonDecode(responseString);
        setState(() {
          loginErrormessage = decodedResult['detail'];
        });
        stopSpinning();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        stopSpinning();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              children: [
                addverticalSpacing(5),
                showAlert(),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      addverticalSpacing(100),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: kboldtextstyleblack,
                        ),
                      ),
                      addverticalSpacing(100),
                      TextFormField(
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        validator: emailvalidator,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          email = value;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Email address',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      addverticalSpacing(40),
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: passwordValidator,
                        obscureText: true,
                        obscuringCharacter: '*',
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          password = value;
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.visibility),
                          hintText: 'Password',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      addverticalSpacing(100),
                      ReusableButton(const Text('Log in'), () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          startSpinning();
                          logUserIn();
                        }
                      }),
                      addverticalSpacing(30),
                      Center(
                        child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'Forgot pasword ?',
                                style: linkStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 15),
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {}),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                      addverticalSpacing(5),
                      Center(
                        child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                              text: 'Don\'t have an account yet ? ',
                              style: defaultStyle,
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'Register',
                                style: linkStyle,
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {
                                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                                        context, RegistrationPage.id);
                                  }),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                      addverticalSpacing(5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried using class constructors to achieve my aim but due to the structure of the app, i get an error from flutter. The mainscreen is a widget that has a bottom navigation that renders three widgets HomeScreen included.
I am a new flutter developer so please exucuse any coding etiquete errors if found.

I am considering just sending the loggedinuseraccesscode string from the loginscreen to the main screen then call the getUserdetailsfromApi function there and use a future builder to show the response as soon as it is ready but i would love it if a solution to this problem is available.

Comment: Where is your provider?

Comment: My bad i have removed it before posting the code

Comment: I used a multiprovider at the top of my widget tree and passed the changenotifier provider  the function Which is UserData(). I then accessed the data of the response where i needed it but i kept getting null. If you have an idea on how i should implement the provider to work i would love to see it.

Comment: Move both getUserDetailsFromApi and logUserIn to the provider and then listen to changes in the provider.

Comment: I could do that but my logUserIn api takes data from textfields inside the LoginPage widgets. once i remove the function and place it inside the provider class, i get alot of errors. the logUserin api also uses data from widgets inside my LoginPage to make the api call.

Comment: Is there any way i could send the data drom my textfield widgets to the provider class that i would create?

Comment: Just pass the needed data as an argument to a function like email and password to logUserIn.

Comment: I think i get your approach. I would then call the function from the provider class inside the onpressed of my login button. Then the function gets triggered and therefore the listeners can provide the data i need from the functions. Is that about it?

Comment: I think you got it. See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Ill get right  on it and provide feedback.

Comment: I have finally solved the issue using provider. Thanks for your input.